# How to rotate single element of 3d Model with Javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a three.js beginner and really impressed by the functionality of it.
I want to load a 3d model with three.js and rotate one element of this model with javascript (e.g. to rotate the hand of a human model or the door of a car model). Is this possible with three.js? Can you provide examples? Which 3d format/loader do you suggest for that purpose?

I tried to move parts of e.g. [this model](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_3ds) - however the object representing the model  after loading it with

```
loader.load( 'models/3ds/portalgun/portalgun.3ds', function ( object ) {..
```

seems not to have a list of sub-elements which I can rotate....So I do not see a chance to select a sub-element of this model which I can transform (e.g. rotate). I am only able to transform (rotate) the complete model.
According to the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D) Object3d has a list of children but in my case it is always empty... Can you provide me an example?

The animation examples such as [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html) seems not to use a loader...

Edit: E.g. how can I move the hand of [this model](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) in JS?

Thank you

Comment: I wrote a 3d rubix-cube-like solverthat has this functionality.  You can see the code here: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/clover-cube.  Example here: http://www.joshuad.net/clover-cube/

Comment: thx, in your case it seems that the model (.json) has a list of child objects - I  do not get them using the recommendet glTF format... Which tool did you use for creating the model? Which export mode did you use?

Comment: Some info here: http://www.joshuad.net/clover-cube/about/

Comment: Thank you! The tutorial is nice! However, I would like to make an animation with an underlying bone model such as the three.js nimation / skinning / blending example - but the moves should be created in Javascript!